# Android SDK projects on Windows and Linux

Tags: android, windows, linux, eclipse

I made Android project on Windows 7 using Android SDK and Eclipse. After moving the whole workspace to Linux, I found that Eclipse doesn't recognize workspace (.metadata), created in Windows. So, I created new workspace and imported existing project to it. Now I see that layout XML files are shown without form designer - only plain XML. Is it possible to move Android Eclipse projects between Windows and Linux?

Comment: If I am not wrong then I think It is related to eclipse and android plugins.

Comment: It should be absolutely possible to move projects (also possibly whole workspaces). I am using linux and I am co-working with guys using Windows 7 and there's no problem to move projects between us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I still don't know why this happened, I found some acceptable workaround: use "Create project from existing source" option in New Android Project dialog. Kind of solution.